# Integrated Windows Authentication with Apache HTTP Server on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, kerberos, integrated-authentication

What is the best way to enable [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) for a PHP web application running on Apache2/Linux? There is a Windows Domain Controller in the network which should be used for authentication.

I found these apache modules:

- [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/)
- [mod_auth_ntlm_winbind](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mod_auth_ntlm_winbind)

But these modules seem to be very outdated (last updated 2007/2008).
Is there a better, more up-to-date way to do this?

Comment: Any specific or contemporary solution to this question?

Comment: Sorry, no. I gave up on this one.

Comment: @FlorianFankhauser have you found a solution?

Comment: @l0w_skilled no, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I believe WDC speaks LDAP, in which case you probably want mod_authnz_ldap instead.

Comment: Yes, but this requires using Basic Authentication which prompts for username/password. I want to use the login information of the windows session so that the user doesn't has to enter his credentials again (single-sign-on).

Answer (score 1):

The best option is [mod_auth_sspi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/), it's reasonable up to date, most recently released in 2011.

I used mod_auth_sspi 1.0.4 with apache 2.2.9 on Windows Server 2003 and it works fine for Windows XP clients.  They get logged in automatically. Here is my config, note that you don't need the SVN bit, but you can see how to restrict to specific groups.

```
# Set that only Domain Users can access this whole server
LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<LocationMatch />
    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "Windows Authentication"
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain dmn.example.com
    SSPIOmitDomain On 
    SSPIOfferBasic Off 
    SSPIUsernameCase lower
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch /trac>
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

# Share subversion repos under http://grp-svn:/svn/REPO_NAME
# We need developers to have read and write access and app support and prod support to have read only.
# The front office dev team also have access.
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath D:\GRP-Data\svn\repos
    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT CHECKOUT>
        Require group "DMN\\GRP-DEV" "DMN\\GRP-SKY Production Support" "DMN\\FS_Sky_RO_DL" 
    </Limit>
    <Limit POST PUT DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK VERSION-CONTROL REPORT CHECKOUT CHECKIN UNCHECKOUT MKWORKSPACE UPDATE LABEL MERGE BASELINE-CONTROL MKACTIVITY ORDERPATCH ACL PATCH SEARCH>
        Require group "DMN\\GRP-DEV" "DMN\\AS_Apache FO_C_DL" 
    </Limit> 
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately mod_auth_sspi only runs on Windows servers. What I need is a solution for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a few hours searching here and there, and finally found the solution.

There is no need to install/enable any apaache modules.

As per the [Integrated Windows Authentication Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication), a response header from your webserver is all what you need.

If you set the `WWW-Authenticate` header in your virtual host configuration, and the server responds with `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`, the client will retry the request with `Authorization` header line contains the base64 encoding of an `InitialContextToken`.

---

In your `vhost.conf` add the header
`Header set WWW-Authenticate 'Negotiate'`

Don't forget to enable the headers module `a2enmod headers && service apache2 restart`

Have a look on [this document](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4559.txt).